# React js useImperativeHandle doesn't use changed state in functions. It's always initial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my code part.

```js
const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);

useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      onMouseDown,
    }),
    [lines]
  );

  const onMouseDown = (e) => {
    const pos = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
    setLines([
      ...lines,
      {
        tool: activeTool,
        color: toolOptions.brush.color,
        size: toolOptions.brush.size,
        points: [pos.x, pos.y],
      },
    ]);
  };
```

I tried to get an updated state at the second click, but that was initial empty array.

Comment: can you please add more complete code to recreate the issue you have?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use a ref to mouseEvent function to refer the lastest values

```
const onMouseDown = (e) => {
    const pos = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
    // use functional updater
    setLines(l => [
      ...l,
      {
        tool: activeTool,
        color: toolOptions.brush.color,
        size: toolOptions.brush.size,
        points: [pos.x, pos.y],
      },
    ]);
  };

const onMouseDownRef = useRef(onMouseDown)
onMouseDownRef.current = onMouseDown;

useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      onMouseDown: (e) => { onMouseDownRef.current(e) },
    }),
    [lines]
  );
```

If this wroks, I will provide some explanation